# How to get the schema name of a table of type regclass in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, system-tables, catalogs, regclass

In writing a function to test if a column `col_name` exists in a table `_tbl`, I'd like to extract the table's schema name, which is passed into the function as a `regclass` parameter (for security??).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION column_exists(_tbl regclass, col_name text)
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
  SELECT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_schema=get_schema($1) 
      AND table_name=get_table($1) 
      AND column_name=$2
    );
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

So if the table name is `'staging.my_table'::regclass`, I'd like to get `staging` from an imaginary function `get_schema`.

*Can I just implement this function with e.g. `split_part(_tbl::text, '.', 1)`?*

*In addition, is it guaranteed that the table name `_tbl`, when converted to text, will always have a schema name? (i.e. not omitting things such as `public.`)*

I'm not very familiar with the `regclass` type. I searched but couldn't find how to extract the schema name, and just wanted to ask first before re-inventing wheels.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I just implement this function with e.g. `split_part(_tbl::text, '.', 1)`?

I'm not sure that would be safe. Instead, I would use,

```
SELECT nspname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class AS c
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS ns
  ON c.relnamespace = ns.oid
WHERE c.oid = _tbl;
```

That is guaranteed to work.

> In writing a function to test if a column `col_name` exists in a table `_tbl`, I'd like to extract the table's schema name, which is passed into the function as a regclass parameter (for security??).

So you could do something like,

```
SELECT nspname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute AS a
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class AS c
  ON a.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS ns
  ON c.relnamespace = ns.oid
WHERE c.oid = _tbl
  AND a.attname = col_name;
```

## Update

If you have a fully-qualified identifier, one with the table name, and schema name inside, You can use [`parse_ident`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/227419/2639) to parse it safely.

Answer (score 13):

To further simplify, you could use a cast to [`regnamespace` - another object identifier type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) introduced with Postgres 9.5

```
SELECT relnamespace::regnamespace::text
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class
WHERE  oid = _tbl;
```

Casting an object identifier type to `text` produces a fully qualified (only if the current `search_path` requires it) and double-quoted (only if necessary) string.

But you don't need any of this if you work with [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION column_exists(_tbl regclass, _col_name text)
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute
   WHERE attrelid = _tbl
   AND   attname = _col_name
   );
$func$;
```

Simpler, shorter, faster.

Comment: cool trick. I like it.