# Where to find the OID of a newly created Schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, query, metadata

I have created a new Schema in my Postgres db. I want to replace an OID in the pg_class table with the OID of the new Schema. But I don't know where to find the OID of the newly created Schema. Can somebody help me with the right queries?

Answer (score 3):

The OID can be found in the [system catalog `pg_namespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-namespace.html).

The simple way to get it: cast to the object identifier type `regnamespace` while connected to the same DB. (Then cast to `oid`, `text` or `bigint` to display the numeric value.):

```
SELECT 'public'::regnamespace::oid;
```

Or, to avoid exceptions (requires Postgres 9.5+):

```
SELECT to_regnamespace('public')::oid;
```

See:

- [How to get the schema name of a table of type regclass in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/200169/how-to-get-the-schema-name-of-a-table-of-type-regclass-in-postgresql/200422#200422)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)

But for your case consider [a_horse's advice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/216511/3684) first. Don't mess with the system catalogs!

Answer (score 2):

#### Do **NOT** change the system catalogs manually!

---

If you want to move a table to a different schema, there is no need to know the  oid of the table or the schema:

[As documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) you can easily do this through `ALTER TABLE`

```
ALTER TABLE old_schema.some_table
    SET SCHEMA new_schema;
```

without having to check or know any oid.

Answer (score -1):

You can run this query to get OID.

```
SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'tbl_name' AND relkind = 'r';
```