# postgres parse_indent() function hang

Tags: postgresql

```
select parse_ident('abc,efi&xyz');
```

Will stay there for ever, not returning. But a similar command will finish.

```
select regexp_split_to_array('abc,efi&xyz', '[,&]');
 regexp_split_to_array 
-----------------------
 {abc,efi,xyz}
(1 row)
```

Not sure what's wrong with my database.  I am running a vacuum full analyze at the moment. Not sure that cause the hang.

Comment: The `parse_ident(qualified_identifier)` is used to split qualified_identifier into an array of identifiers, removing any quoting of individual identifiers.

Comment: @Kemin: I am not sure what you are asking. Please check the active process to define which processes are locking your `vacuum`.

Answer (score 2):

You're losing error messages,

```
# select parse_ident('abc,efi&xyz');
ERROR:  string is not a valid identifier: "abc,efi&xyz"
```

They also do different things:

- [`parse_ident`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) takes a string a *fully-qualified identifier* -- something you can use to identify a thing in a database, and returns the breakdown of it in an array. For example, if you had a column named `abc,efi&xyz` on a table named `table` in a schema named `schema` in a database named `db`, you *could* do,

  ```
  SELECT parse_ident('"abc,efi&xyz".table.schema.db');
             parse_ident           
  ---------------------------------
   {"abc,efi&xyz",table,schema,db}
  (1 row)
  ```

  From this point you could use array addressing to identify the table, `(parse_ident(...)[2])`.
- `regexp_split_to_array` takes *any string* and simply splits it returning an array. Unlike `parse_ident` it doesn't require a fully-qualified identifier, and it doesn't understand ANSI-quotes inside the identifier (as I used in my example above).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: I was running DbSchema program that is locking a lot of tables including the meta tables.

After terminating DbSchema, things started moving. I figured it out when I tried to 'drop table tmp;', and it also got hung. After terminating DbSchema, the drop table finished. Then the parse_ident() started to work. For some reason, DbSchema is locking the database even the meta data.

```
lbwf3=# select parse_ident('abc,efi&xyz');
ERROR:  string is not a valid identifier: "abc,efi&xyz"
```

Comment: You should report that as a bug for DbSchema - locking up a the system tables like that is an extremely nasty thing to do. I can't even think of a way how that could happen "accidently".

Comment: DbSchema (shell script around a java program) is a reasonable affordable product, not worth the time.  For many versions, the product got some shell script error and cash, each time after automatic update I have to fix it manually.  I think finally they get it right. I send my fix to them several time; reported the bug several times.